# Why is # (hashtag) included in websites with ajax?

Tags: ajax, url, hashtag, html4

I did some research on the reason why # (hashtag) is used in a URL when ajax is used, but I couldn't find an answer. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean what the purpose of it is, or the reason they included it?

Comment: History (changing the hash adds new URL to the browser's history) and deep linking (you can detect the presence of a hash on page load and make an AJAX call to display relevant content). BTW it's not a *hashtag*, in the context of URLs it's called a *Fragment Identifier*.

Comment: @Feign I mean purpose and reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashtags are added to the URL when using AJAX because AJAX doesn't change the url and then if you click Previous button of the browser after doing many AJAX requests, you will be moved to a very earlier page ( because the browser will consider all Ajax generated pages as one page because they gave one URL). That's why Hashtags are added to simulate the movement from one page to an other. and then the Previous/Next buttons of the browser will work just fine.